# Ask about PySpark Pipeline model and the problem with udf function

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, data-science, jupyter

I have a spark dataframe like this:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('/work/workplace/thanglq2/tmp/df_personas_20230620')
```

```
from pprint import pprint

def get_string_and_numeric_cols(df):
    # Get list of dtypes for each column
    dtypes = df.dtypes
    # Keep only columns of type 'string' 
    string_cols = [name for name,type in dtypes if type == 'string' and name != 'CUSTOMER_ID']
    # Keep only columns of type 'int' or 'double' ('double' is used for floating-point numbers)
    numeric_cols = [name for name,type in dtypes if type != 'string']
    return string_cols, numeric_cols

cat_cols, num_cols = get_string_and_numeric_cols(df)
old_cols = cat_cols + num_cols
W = [w1_w2(f) for f in old_cols]
```

w1_w2 is my function to define a weight for each feature f in df. The problem happend when I tried to building a pipeline like this:applying the StringIndexer on string columns, then apply StandardScaler on all features, then element-wise multiply features with W.

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, StandardScaler
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT


# Let's assume df is your DataFrame
df = df.fillna(0, subset=num_cols)  # assuming numeric_cols is a list of your numeric column names
df = df.fillna('unknown', subset=cat_cols)  # assuming string_cols is a list of your string column names

print("Filled NaN values.")

# StringIndexer for categorical columns
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=c, outputCol="{0}_indexed".format(c)) for c in cat_cols]

# New columns (indexed categorical and numerical)
new_cols = [c + "_indexed" for c in cat_cols] + num_cols


# VectorAssembler for all columns
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=new_cols, outputCol="all_features")

# StandardScaler for all columns
scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="all_features", outputCol="scaledFeatures", withStd=True, withMean=False)

# Element-wise multiplication using UDF
multiply_udf = udf(lambda features: Vectors.sparse(features.size, features.indices, features.values * W), VectorUDT())

# Define the stages of the pipeline
stages = indexers + [assembler, scaler]

# Create the pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)

# Fit the pipeline to the DataFrame
pipeline_model = pipeline.fit(df)

# Transform the DataFrame
output_df = pipeline_model.transform(df)

# Perform element-wise multiplication
multiplied_df = output_df.withColumn("multipliedFeatures", multiply_udf("scaledFeatures"))

# Show the result
multiplied_df.show()
```

then I put it to Kmeans on PySpark:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cost = []
for k in range(5, 30):  # Change the range as needed
    kmeans = KMeans()\
        .setK(k)\
        .setSeed(1) \
        .setFeaturesCol("filterFeatures")\
        .setPredictionCol("cluster")
    model = kmeans.fit(df_transformed)
    print(f'k = {k}, score={model.summary.trainingCost}')

# Plot the cost
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize =(8, 6))
ax.plot(range(5, 30), cost[:])
ax.set_xlabel('k')
ax.set_ylabel('cost')
plt.show()
```

And it throws out an error like this :

```
PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\thanglq2\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12368\2960499992.py", line 28, in <lambda>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (24,) (82,)
```

I'm a newbie to PySpark, and I really don't know what to do. Please help me.

I have tried it so many times,